# How do I add click events to a tinyMCE 4 file_picker_callback window?

Tags: jquery, onclicklistener, tinymce-4

I'm trying to add jQuery click event listeners to my custom file browser window for my `file_picker_callback` but I'm not having success.

I'm able to add click events to my *first* popup window by [using](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:setup):

```
setup : function(ed) {
      ed.on('click', function(e) {
          console.log('Editor was clicked');
      });
   }
```

My first window is the **Insert/edit image** window that's built into tinyMCE 4.2 however, this is not my desired target. My desired target is the window that is launched when I click the file browser button pictured below. When you invoke `file_picker_callback`, you get a file browser icon (circled).

[image]

When I click on the file browser button, I have a second window appear which I'll be using as my file browser, *this* window is where I want to add my events.

Below the code I'm using to invoke my `file_picker_callback`...

**init:**

```
tinymce.init({
    //...
    file_picker_callback: function (callback, value, meta) {
        imageFilePicker(callback, value, meta);
    }
});
```

**code for second window:**

```
var imageFilePicker = function (callback, value, meta) {
    tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
        title: 'Image Picker',
        url: '/images/getimages',
        width: 900,
        height: 550,
        onPostRender: function () {
            doCrap();
        },
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Insert',
            onclick: function () {
                tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.close();
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close'
           }],
        }, {
            oninsert: function (url) {
                callback(url);
                alert("derp");
           },
        });
   };
```

### My Question

How would I add an event handler to my **second** window?